# List @ tag auto completes in vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete, tags, supertab

I'd like to plant a number of `@tags` (e.g. `@sea_ice`, `@models`) in my markdown files when editing in vim. Currently I'm using SuperTab to tab-complete ordinary words. However if I hit `<tab>` after the `@` symbol, it won't give me a list of all `@tags`, but rather a long list of all words found in the current context.

I noticed that SuperTab allows custom context definitions, however, as I know nothing about vim scripting and the documentation contains only 2 examples, I'm unable to script it myself.

After bit searching around I think I probably need to define a new custom omni complete function, specifically the 2nd half of the function:

`function! TagComplete(findstart, base)
  if a:findstart
    " locate the start of the word
    let line = getline('.')
    let start = col('.') - 1
    while start > 0 && line[start - 1] != '@'
      let start -= 1
    endwhile
    return start
  else
    " find @tag
    let res = []
    ????
    ????
    endif
    return res
  endif
endfun`

This is the code I'm working on. But I don't know how to test it or where is the right place to put it. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of struggling and searching for help, I figured out one solution.

Firstly create a `completefunc` that searches for `@tags` in the current file (Credits to cherryberryterry: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/4dg1rx/how_to_define_custom_omnifunc_in_vim_seeking/):

```
function! CompleteTags(findstart, base)
    if a:findstart
        return match(matchstr(getline('.'), '.*\%' . col('.') . 'c'), '.*\(^\|\s\)\zs@')
    else
        let matches = []

        " position the cursor on the last column of the last line
        call cursor(line('$'), col([line('$'), '$']))

        " search backwards through the buffer for all matches
        while searchpos('\%(^\|\s\)\zs' . (empty(a:base) ? '@' : a:base) . '[[:alnum:]_]*', 'bW') != [0, 0]
            let matches += [matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c@[[:alnum:]_]*')]
        endwhile

        return filter(matches, "v:val != '@'")
    endif
endfunction
set completefunc=CompleteTags
```

The put the following in `.vimrc` to setup tab-completion using SuperTab:

```
function! TagCompleteContext()
    let line = getline('.')
    if line[col('.') - 2] == '@'
        return "\<c-x>\<c-u>"
    endif
endfunction


let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
let g:SuperTabCompletionContexts = ['TagCompleteContext', 's:ContextText']
let g:SuperTabContextDefaultCompletionType = "<c-p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used SuperTab so I have no idea if and how this solution could be made to work with that plugin, but it's pretty easy with the built-in manual completion.

1. If it doesn't exist already, create this directory structure:

   ```
   ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/
   ```
2. In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`, add this line:

   ```
   setlocal define=@
   ```
3. In a markdown buffer, type `@` and press `<C-x><C-d>`.

   [image]

See `:help 'define'` and `:help ctrl-x_ctrl-d`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It kind of works but not quite. When I have 6 such `@tags` in a test file and use your method, the completion only gives me 2 choices (the first 2), and it cycles through the 2. Is there a length limit parameter or what?

Comment: I figured out that the `define` is used to mark a definition **line**. In my case I have multiple `@tags` in a single line so all subsequent tags are not recognized. Is there a way to solve this?